# Merge [frontpage] with [homepage]

Tags: support, status-completed, meta, retag-request, synonym-request

MSE has these tags:

> 64 questions tagged [frontpage](/questions/tagged/frontpage)
>
>   For questions involving the site front page.
>
> 97 questions tagged [homepage](/questions/tagged/homepage)
>
>   The initial view of a Stack Exchange site
>     that consists mainly of a list of questions.

Aren't these the same thing?  I suggest that these tags be merged.

Which should be the master, and which the synonym? 
I don't have an opinion.  But here are some relevant facts:
in a text search of this site, "frontpage" trails "homepage"
by 198 results to 911 results,
but "front page" leads "home page" 1,360 to 657. 
And Meta Unix & Linux just created a "homepage" tag;
it does not have a "frontpage" tag.

Comment: @Glorfindel Why was it decided not to merge the tags, or follow the answer which says it should be two words?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I have a feeling somebody will try to create [frontpage] again. Homepage is [also written as a single word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_page), just like 'username' and 'filename'. I have no preference, so I'm not inclined to overwrite the current situation.

Comment: @Glorfindel Understand the naming situation. However, it doesn't make sense to me why you didn't also merge the tags at the same time as creating the synonym - that will also prevent others from creating the old name again.

Comment: @Sonic the tags are merged, what do I miss here?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard No, they're not. The tag listing for [tag:homepage] lists questions that still use the [tag:frontpage] tag. Also, the list shows 218 questions using it, but the tag mouseover popup only lists 128 questions; that's because there are 90 questions currently using the synonym tag instead.

Comment: @Glorfindel please remove the wrong tag then, the request was to merge, not just add synonym. Personally I don't really care for merging, but I do care for wrong status tags.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Per the extended tag wiki for [tag:status-completed], *an alternate solution that still solves the same problem/concern will still be considered completion*, so this isn't an incorrect application of the tag. I'm just wondering why it wasn't actioned as per the request, though.

Comment: @Sonic I agree in the general case, but here the request is very specific and clearly worded. It's not done, so the completed is misleading. Sadly, it's pretty common on MSE, sometimes I flag, and in very rare cases mods fix it.

Comment: Somehow I thought that merging two tags automatically removed the synonym, but my knowledge is a little rusty. And what's the additional value of a merge over a tag synonym? That it can't be easily reversed?

Comment: @Glorfindel There is an option to create a synonym in the UI for merging tags. One advantage I can think of is to prevent users from being inappropriately awarded Organizer badges if they make edits to the content without changing the tags, as the automatic replacement with the master tag will be considered a tag change (it considers any minor change, including cases where the tags are the same but in a different order if their popularity has changed since the last revision). It'll also ensure tag popups show the correct number of questions.

Comment: Also, users with a gold tag badge cannot close questions with the synonym tag as duplicates if they have the badge for the master tag, and if they make any edit to the question, which will auto-swap the tag for the master, they'll still be prevented as the system will consider them the first to add the tag (i.e., the anti-gaming provision will kick in).

Answer (score 7):

I agree that they should be merged and propose that [homepage](/questions/tagged/homepage) be merged into [home-page](/questions/tagged/home-page) first so that the latter can become the master of both [frontpage](/questions/tagged/frontpage) and [homepage](/questions/tagged/homepage).

"Home page" is two words, and [tag naming conventions here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) are that hyphens are used between words.